# Moving a content of a page based on the size of the fixed elements with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a web page that displays a list of item with variable length. There are two panels at the top of the page that display information about the selected item from the list. Both or just one can be hidden by the user to see more items in the list. If the panels are displayed, I need them to be fixed - even when scrolling through the list, they are always visible. If the user hides some panels, I want the list of items to move to the area where the fixed panel was.

The situation is shown in the picture. The green and yellow panels must always be seen until the user hides it. The list must move according to space above.

[image]

Is there a possibility to do this with HTML and CSS?

Comment: _“Is there a possibility to do this with HTML and CSS?”_ - probably, at least when JS comes into play as well. But, “is there a possibility” is not a suitable question for this site - please go read [ask], and then show us what code you have so far, what you have tried.

Comment: The use of the term _"fixed"_ is a bit vague here. Normally, in CSS, a fixed element would stay at the top (or elsewhere) of the viewport and content would scroll behind the fixed element. Creating an overly. Is this the intent? The mockup seems to suggest that there's simple to elements before a third that can be collapsed an may not actually be fixed in a CSS sense.

Comment: @hungerstar I want the two panels to stay at the top of the viewport and content (the list of items in my case) would scroll behind them. However, the panels may be hidden by a user. In this case, I need to ensure that the content will move up. The mockup shows that user hides yellow panel and the content moved up and now the content only would scroll behind the green panel (the green one is hidden/has 0 height).

Comment: You're going to need some JS then, as any fixed positioned elements would be taken out of the document flow. Taking them out of the document flow prevents the content from shifting up when you close (change the height of) one of the panels. To allow content to scroll behind the panels, you need to take them out of the document flow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can put your list inside a div and set the div to have a fixed height as well, then the items below will be scrollable.

See this example ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rLnxbn7n/)):

```css
.panel-1, .panel-2{
  height: 100px;
}
.panel-1{
  background: red;
}
.panel-2{
  background: blue;
}

.list{
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.list-group{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.list-item{
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="panel-1">Information</div>
  <div class="panel-2">More information</div>
  <div class="list">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-item">Item 1</li>
      <li class="list-item">Item 2</li>
      <li class="list-item">Item 3</li>
      <li class="list-item">Item 4</li>
      <li class="list-item">Item 5</li>
      <li class="list-item">Item 6</li>
      <li class="list-item">Item 7</li>
      <li class="list-item">Item 8</li>
      <li class="list-item">Item 9</li>
      <li class="list-item">Item 10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```